# CakePHP Shared core for multiple apps

Tags: php, cakephp

On my local setup I have a load of different CakePHP websites. I'm using a Mac so the folder structure is something like `~/Users/cameron/Sites/sample-website` and then within each of these websites I will have the typical Cake folder and App folder.

What I would like to do is have just a core cake folder and then have ALL the sites pull from that one cake core so I don't have the same stuff several times over. I have been reading some tutorials on the web: http://rickguyer.com/cakephp-one-core-many-apps/

So I have my cake folder here: `~/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3/` and then my site here: `~/Users/cameron/Sites/sample-site/` and in this folder I have the usual app folder and htaccess to tell it where to find webroot etc.

Now I have edited the index.php file inside webroot like the tutorial BUT have only changed one line because I haven't moved my files OUTSIDE of the App folder like he does. So the only like I have changed is as follows:

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH'))
{
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '..'.DS.'..'.DS.'cake-1.3');
}
```

As far as I can tell that is correctly looking two directories up and finding a folder called `cake-1.3` however it just gives a error 500?

Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks

EDIT:

Even doing this doesn't work???
Which If I echo: `echo CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH;` gives `/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3` and if I paste that in the address bar it loads up the cake folder so it's definitely the correct folder structure JUST it doesn't like looking at cake outside of the main url?

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH'))
{
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'Users'.DS.'cameron'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'cake-1.3'); echo CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH;
}
```

Comment: Are the websites related in anyway? (e.g. selling the same products, sharing a data base, etc.) Why do you want to have them on the same server?

Comment: @John Isaacks: It's not the same APP code that is being shared, but the same Core framework for CakePHP. It prevents having to have multiple copies of the core on the same server. Then when you want to update the core, it can be updated in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right on the money with:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'Users'.DS.'cameron'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'cake-1.3');
```

Just make sure that Users sits in root. In other words, when you go to terminal you can get to this directory by typing: `cd /Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3`

It looks like you may be on a MAC. If so, your linking is correct. Most of the time what I find is you have done a copy paste of the app directory and it does not get the .htaccess files. I would check those first. But here is a comprehensive list of what you should verify:

1. Make sure the host is pointing to
   the correct directory
   (`/Users/cameron/Sites/sample-site/`)
2. Verify mod_rewrite is in fact on.
3. Verify you have copied the `.htaccess`
   file in both the
   `/Users/cameron/Sites/sample-site/`
   and the
   `/Users/cameron/Sites/sample-site/webroot`
   directories.
4. Confirm that the
   `/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3/`
   directory has a directory called
   cake in it that contains the core.

Once all of this is confirmed, you will be good as gold!

Happy Coding!

**UPDATE:**
When the index.php file looks for the cake core, it will look for a directory inside the location you are pointing to for another directory called cake. So in your case:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'Users'.DS.'cameron'.DS.'Sites'.DS.'cake-1.3');
```

You must have the cake directory inside `/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3`. Your directory structure will look like:

```
/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3/cake
/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3/cake/libs
/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3/cake/config
/Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3/cake/console
etc.
```

**CakePHP 3.0+**
In CakePHP 3.0+ this configuration is moved out of webroot/index.php to App/Config/paths.php

Comment: All is correct EXCEPT `cake-1.3/` doesn't contain a cake folder! It IS the cake folder... changing it so their IS a cake folder does in fact fix the problem BUT i want cake-1.3 to be the cake core!

Comment: Exactly. Unzip the cake 1.3 download and change the main directory name to cake-1.3. Leave everything in tact. You will see the app, cake, plugins, etc. folders in there. It will still contain the cake core, but it must be accessed via /your/directory/to/cake-1.3/cake. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you see the lib folder under cake-1.3, you need to change cake-1.3 back to cake and then put it in a folder called cake-1.3 and you will be working.

Comment: What if I want it to be called Cake-1.3 instead of just Cake though?

Comment: You can have it called cake-1.3... but the core must reside in the cake directory. There are other files that are specific to the core that sit outside the cake directory (i.e. plugins, vendors, app). So you can still name the folder one level up, but you cannot rename the cake folder without modifying the code itself. All of the functions within core look for the `cake` directory. But this is handy. When you want to make a new site, you can copy the app directory from cake-1.3 and use it to make another site within Sites. It keeps it simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your php.ini, you can add the path to Cake core there. Doing it this way means you don't have to change webroot/index.php at all. Example in php.ini:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/something/phpinc/cakephp2/lib"
```

According to the [CakePHP 2.x docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#using-one-cakephp-checkout-for-multiple-applications), this is the recommended way to share the Cake core (assuming you have access to your php.ini).

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one cake core but you must have one app folder (containing MVC) by site.

Comment: Yes I only have one Cake core folder but that has been moved out of the website directory so that other sites can share the same core.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a misunderstanding of the folder structure of CakePHP?

From the docs ([CakePHP folder structure](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/899/CakePHP-Folder-Structure)):

- The app folder will be where you work *your* magic: it’s where your application’s files will be placed.
- The cake folder is where we’ve worked *our* magic. Make a personal commitment not to edit files in this folder. We can’t help you if you’ve modified the core.

So the `cake` folder shouldn't change between all of your uses, therefore you have 1 copy. You can always change some of the functionality of the core by making your own changes in the `app` folder i.e. extending.

Comment: Yes I know this. But I want to have several apps all sharing a core cake folder so I don't have to update several versions of the same core.

Comment: My apologies. You could probably put the `index.php` into the `app` folder, but I imagine you would need to change file paths in config files. How about keeping the same structure, but using a symlink (or alias) for the `cake` directory, to point to your single code base.

Comment: Yes please see updated OP for what I have changed to see the new location of cake core files. But I still get an error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to edit index.php.

Just put an alias (or link in UNIX) to your cake folder in each of your sites folder. Works perfectly. Same goes for plugins and vendors folder.

Comment: Not if the .htaccess files are the issue. What @Cameron is doing correct. There is probably another issue (like missing .htaccess files).

Comment: sure, if .htaccess is missing there will be an issue. Nevertheless my solution is working and there is no need to edit index.php. In all my sites I have a link (or alias) to a unique and centralized cake folder, plugins folder and vendors folder, like so: cake -> /Library/Cake/cake, plugins -> /Library/Cake/plugins