# cakephp for multiple static sites

Tags: cakephp, static

I have successfully created a static website using cakephp to create the static html files using the console.

However, what I want to do now is have a console script that can create multiple websites from the same shared data, with each website using data that is unique to it, but sharing the db as a source.

So, how do I set up the app folder in relation to each website? Do I need a separate installation of cakephp for each site? Or can I have a shared App folder in cgi-bin or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can share the CakePHP core between multiple apps, however you will need a separate 'app' folder for each website (with the appropriate structure). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706245/cakephp-shared-core-for-multiple-apps) for more details. Essentially you will need to modify the `index.php` file in each `app/webroot` folder to point to the CakePHP core. I use this technique and it's much easier to maintain with only one core as opposed to a whole separate installation of Cake for each site.