# Cakephp multiple sites share same resources

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have built a `cakephp` base e-commerce site. Now some similar sites need to make as same as built one with different name. All sites will belong to same server as siblings. So in that case I want to share same lib and app i.e all resources from built one.

Is that possible with cakephp? Or what do I need to do to accomplish this tasks. Please help me on that.

Note: also seen this [CakePHP Shared core for multiple apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706245/cakephp-shared-core-for-multiple-apps). but it only focus on using `lib`. But I want to u the whole site content. In other word, it will be clone with some very few changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could define additional paths with `App::build()` in `app/Config/bootstrap.php`, see [Additional Class Paths](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths).

Comment: got that. but in that case i need to include that `lib`, `app` folders and some other files also. but is there any other way without that. using `htacess` or some other way with redirect or anyother

Answer (score 0):

What about using Themes http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html (you can have same code base - controller, model) but different cloned themes for each site. The AppController beforeFilter can handle switching the themes based on domain.

If the few changes are related only to content presentation, i think this is the way to go.